# Clearing unwanted input in Java

Tags: java, input, newline

I am using a 'ConsoleSupport' class which handles the receiving and validation of input from the user. One problem I noticed was that if I asked for an integer (menu option) in my console UI first, then asked for a couple of Strings, the first String would be empty. The dreaded newline character strikes again! I used the following in my getType methods before returning the value to make it work:

```
if(in.hasNextLine())
    in.nextLine();
```

Does anyone have an alternative, more 'elegant' solution to dealing with input that is not wanted?

The (abbreviated) class is below for reference

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class will reliably and safely retrieve input from the user
 * without crashing. It can collect an integer, String and a couple of other
 * types which I have left out for brevity
 * 
 * @author thelionroars1337
 * @version 0.3 Tuesday 25 September 2012
 */
public class ConsoleSupport
{

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    /** 
     * Prompts user for an integer, until it receives a valid entry
     * 
     * @param prompt The String used to prompt the user for an int input
     * @return The integer
     */
    public static int getInteger(String prompt)
    {
        String input = null;
        int integer = 0;
        boolean validInput = false;

        while(!validInput)
        {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            input = in.next();
            if(input.matches("(-?)(\\d+)"))
            {
                integer = Integer.parseInt(input);
                validInput = true;
            }
            else
            {
                validInput = false;
                System.out.println("Sorry, this input is incorrect! Please try again.");
            }
        }

        if(in.hasNextLine())
            in.nextLine(); // flush the Scanner

        return integer;
    } 


    /**
     * Prompts the user to enter a string, and returns the input
     * 
     * @param prompt The prompt to display
     * @return The inputted string
     */
    public static String getString(String prompt)
    { 
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Input from `System.in` isn't available to be read until the user hits enter. Because of that, there's an extra newline in the Scanner's buffer after the integer. So when you call `Scanner.nextInt()` you read the integer, but the next time you call `Scanner.nextLine()`, you'll read up to the newline in the buffer and it would return a blank String.

One way to deal with it is to just always call `nextLine()` and use `Integer.parseInt()` like you're doing above. You could probably skip the regex match and instead just catch the `NumberFormatException`:

```
    while(!validInput)
    {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        input = in.nextLine();
        try {
            integer = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());
            validInput = true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            validInput = false;
            System.out.println("Sorry, this input is incorrect! Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

And you wouldn't need to check if there's an extra line at the end and flush the scanner.